# Ajax call only if the jquery validation is valid

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation

I have a form and ajax call.data are filled in form and goes to remote at the same time user is created in my database using ajax call.but the problem is with validation,which validation should apply here
for example i apply any jquery validation i need to test if the form is valid and then i can call ajax if the form is valid other wise the database will be filled with blank data
i tried with bvalidator but i don't know how to detect the form is valid or invalid using any jquery validator library

```
<form id="inform" action="http://site.com">
<input type="text" id="name" />
<input type="text" id="email" />
<input type="button" name="subaction" id="infuse" />
</form>

    <script language ="javascript" type = "text/javascript" >
    $na= jQuery.noConflict();
    $na(document).ready(function(){ 
            $na('#infuse').click(function(){


                         var name= $na('#name').val();

                         var email = $na('#email').val();


                 $na.ajax({
                             type: "POST",
                             url: '<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/user_create.php',
                             data: 'name='+name+'&email='+email,
                             cache: false,


                             success: function(result){
                                                     jQuery('.err_msg').html(result);
                                                      jQuery("#inform").submit();  
                                               }
                                          });


                    }); 
     });

    </script>
```

Comment: There seems to be a typo in your question. You really want to store the value in `email` in a variable called `age` and never use it again?

Comment: Couldn't you possibly write your own validations, that better suit your application?

Comment: ya by mistake i wrote it its not original version,but all i need is valid the form before ajax call and if valid go to ajax process

Comment: What validations do you want to run exactly?

Comment: i use jquey bvalidator.but i could not find how to check form is valid or not.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this

```
<script language ="javascript" type = "text/javascript" >
$na= jQuery.noConflict();
var name;
var email;
var options10 = {

    // shows or hides error all messages container after validation completes
    onAfterAllValidations: function(elements, formIsValid){

        // if validation failed
        if(!formIsValid)
            callAjax();
        else{
            //do something
        }
    }
};


function callAjax(){
  $na.ajax({
                           type: "POST",
                           url: '<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/user_create.php',
                           data: 'name='+name+'&email='+email,
                           cache: false,
                           success: function(result){
                                                 jQuery('.err_msg').html(result);
                                                  jQuery("#inform").submit();  
                                           }
                                 });
}
$na(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#inform').bValidator(options10);

        $na('#infuse').click(function(){


                     name= $na('#name').val();
                     email = $na('#email').val();

         }); 
});

</script>
```

I haven't checked this, but hopefully , this works. The important point is, you could use the callbacks : **onAfterAllValidations**.

Comment: Hello jquery validation uses input type submit but when i use it after validation successful the form submits and my ajax call do not run so what should do because previously i was using input type button and submit form after ajax call.